# display image from SD card to view pager android

Tags: android

hi have an activity which reads images from drawable folder and shows them in viewpager. below is my code for that. Now I want to show images from my SD card in to viewpager. what changes should be made in below code to read images from SD card and display them in viewpager.

```
public class TestClass extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testclass);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
      ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_testclass);
      myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      myPager.setCurrentItem(0);


        }


private int imageArra[] = {

         R.drawable.a01,
         R.drawable.a02,
         R.drawable.a03
};
```

and here is PagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
 Activity activity;
 int imageArray[];

 public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
  imageArray = imgArra;
  activity = act;
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return imageArray.length;
 }

 public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
  ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
  view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  view.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[position]);
  ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
  return view;
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
  ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
  return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
 }

 @Override
 public Parcelable saveState() {
  return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change view.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[position]);
to **view.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);**

because Background resource not effected by ScaleType

Comment: Yes, dont have Eclipse rigth here :) Get from my mind memory :)

Comment: Try view.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
Not use Background - its for Layouts (like Relative,Liear and etc.)